# HashMap in ArrayList viewing on Listview Android

Tags: java, android, list, listview, hashmap

All my code so far:

I am putting the string that I want to show on the screen in List of *hardlist*.(getDestinationCity and getTotalPrice)
However I see only getTotalPrice values on the screen. getDestinationCity field is empty. I guess I only show the Values (getTotalPrice)  on screen except Keys (getDestinationCity).

How can I figure it out?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    List<HashMap<String, String>> hardlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            String getTotalPrice = null;
            String getDestinationCity = null;
            ListView lv;
            ListAdapter listAdapter;

        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                deserilaze();

                String[] from = new String[]{getDestinationCity, getTotalPrice};
                int[] to = new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.price};

                listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, hardlist,  R.layout.list_item, from, to);

                lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }

           public void deserilaze(){

                Gson gson = new Gson();

                AirJson airJson = gson.fromJson(airFullJson, AirJson.class);

                for (Itinerary itini : airJson.getResult().getItineraries()) {
        //            System.out.println("\n");
                    String getSelectionID = itini.getSelectionId();
                    getTotalPrice = itini.getPriceInfo().getPriceBreakdown().getTotalPrice().toString();
                    String getCurrency = itini.getPriceInfo().getCurrency();

        //            System.out.println("Itinerary: " + "\n" + getSelectionID + "\n" + getTotalPrice + "\t" + getCurrency);


                    for (Trip tripin : itini.getTrips()) {
                        getDestinationCity = tripin.getDestinationCity();
                        String getOriginCity = tripin.getOriginCity();
                        String getValidatingCarrier = tripin.getValidatingCarrier();
                        String getDepartureTime = tripin.getDepartureTime();
                        String getArrivalTime = tripin.getArrivalTime();

        //                System.out.println("Trip: " + "\n" + getDestinationCity + "\n" + getOriginCity + "\n" + getValidatingCarrier + "\n" +
        //                        getDepartureTime + "\n" + getArrivalTime);

                        for (Segment segmenti : tripin.getSegments()){

                            String getSegmentOrigin = segmenti.getDepartureTime();
                            String getSegmentDestination = segmenti.getArrivalTime();

        //                    System.out.println("Segment: " + "\n" + getSegmentOrigin + "\n" + getSegmentDestination);

                        }

                    }

                    HashMap<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    list.put(getDestinationCity, getTotalPrice);

                    hardlist.add(list);

                }

            }
}
```

[This is the debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfU9V.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do like this:

```
//these are the names of the columns
String[] from = new String[]{"DestinationCity", "TotalPrice"};
...
//you associate to the key DestinationCity the value getDestinationCity
list.put("DestinationCity", getDestinationCity);
//you associate to the key TotalPrice the value getTotalPrice
list.put("TotalPrice", getTotalPrice);
```

So you will have a list of maps, each map having two entries (so having two key and their associated values).
Also, read carefully the meaning of the SimpleAdapter constructor parameters:

> Constructor
>   @param **context** The context where the View associated with this SimpleAdapter is running
>   @param **data** A List of Maps. Each entry in the List corresponds to one row in the list. The Maps contain the data for each row, *and should include all the entries specified in "from"*
>   @param **resource** Resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"
>   @param **from** A list of column names that will be added to the Map associated with each item.
>   @param **to** The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter.

Comment: but I will have thousands fields in the future. I think it's not a good idea to write them all by hand. I referred the string by getDestinationCity, getTotalPrice.

Comment: The `from` parameter is `A list of column names that will be added to the Map associated with each item`. So here you only put the names of your columns... Will you have thousands of columns ? I guess not...